# Activerecord combine sum and limit does not work

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using Rails 3.2 I try to sum up certain attributes of a model but limit it to eg the last 10. Why does it always sum up all of the elements.

```
Shop.limit(10)
```

gives me an ActiveRecord::Relation object consisting of 10 shop. But if I do

```
Shop.limit(10).sum(:id, :order => "created_at DESC")
```

I get the sum of all shop ids, not just 10. Same goes for

```
Shop.sum(:id, :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 10)
```

Is there a way to sum up just the ids of just the last/first 10 shops?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

> Shop.select("id").order("created_at desc").limit(10).collect(&:id).sum

it will give sum of last ten ids